# how to stop jquery hover slidetoggle queuing

Tags: jquery, queue, slidetoggle

I am trying to create a horizontal menu, which when hovered, expands upwords.
The problem is when you hover over them all quickly, they have a horrible jumping effect which  looks nasty. How can I prevent this, and also is there a better way to write this function?

```
 $(".toggle_hov").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".toggle_cont").stop().slideToggle();
    $('.toggle_hov.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('.toggle_cont');
    $(".toggle_cont").not($this).slideUp();
  });
```

many thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/Js5Z5/1

Comment: `stop(true)`??? http://jsfiddle.net/Js5Z5/2/

Comment: `clearQueue` also work http://jsfiddle.net/Js5Z5/3/

Comment: thanks so much, stop(true) works the best! jsfiddle.net/Js5Z5/2

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use some delay in hover this way it will only open slide up the many if user hovers for given time. it wont slide open if you quickly move over it.

```
 var delay=500, setTimeoutConst;
    $(".toggle_hov").hover(function () {        
        that = $(this);
         setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function () {
            $(that).find(".toggle_cont").slideToggle();
            $('.toggle_hov.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
            $(that).toggleClass('active');
            var $this = $(this).parent().find('.toggle_cont');
            $(".toggle_cont").not($this).slideUp();
          }, delay)
    }, function(){
         clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst );

      });
```

Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Js5Z5/1/)